Facets Issue with Importing and Vectorizing Data in Azure Search
I'm encountering an issue while working with importing and vectorizing data in my project.
After importing and vectorizing data, I noticed that I have an excessive number of chunks, which is fine as it helps me stay under the maximum token input limits of embedding models.
Where I encounter the issue is when I want to create filtering by metadata_content_type. I marked the field as facetable, and as a result, for 1 PPTX file, I am getting a count of 19 for the value "pptx".
I guess it is because the engine sees chunks as documents and doesn't distinguish them in any manner. Is there something I can do about this as I need to have embeddings on large documents which means chunking is required but also I need to have filtering with facets as well?
My expectations are to get distinct values for facets counts. And later while doing search to not get duplicates.

Get results for distinct values; this is not supported in AI search. Refer to this QnA for more information.
Since you have the chunked documents as separate records, you will get many outputs even for the same file.
The only possible solution is if you are using an SDK for query search. After getting results, create distinct records based on metadata_storage_path or metadata_storage_name.
Here is the sample code:
def get_distinct_storage_paths(data, content_type):
    seen_paths = set()
    for record in data:
        path = record.get("metadata_storage_path")
        if path:
            seen_paths.add(path)

    return list(seen_paths)

distinct_paths = get_distinct_storage_paths(data)

Here, the data you pass should be the search query results containing records for metadata_content_type as pptx. This function returns distinct file names or paths.
There is no other way to achieve this in the portal.

Thanks for your response, but how would you do faceting, as results of facets query I got {"pptx", 19} I don't know whether or not they are unique values

Usually when you do chunking, the records will be having different chunk with chunk id but origin of those chunks will be same document or file name or file path. You search query along with mera data file name to know if that particular chunk belongs to same or different document.

I understand, but that will not help me with faceting, I am speaking of this type of query:
{
"search": "*",
"queryType": "simple",
"select": "",
"searchFields": "",
"filter": "",
"facets": [ "metadata_content_type"],
"orderby": "",
"count": true
}
where I get
{
"count": 19,
"value": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
},
for just one PPTX file inside my storage

You have 19 records with value application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation that is the reason you are getting count 19. If you wonder how 19 recrods for single file, that is because of chunking. As i mentioned you cannot get the distinct  values it is not supported.
